# Can't start a gnome session over ssh

Tags: gnome, ssh, x11-forwarding, gnome-session

I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04 running on it. I want to start a gnome session over my PC which also runs on Ubuntu.

I setup my OpenSSH configs for the client (PC) and the server (Pi) to support X11 forwarding and I can run UI apps like `gedit` or `nautilus` with no problems after logging in with `ssh -X user@device`. However, when I try to run `gnome-session` only a non-descriptive error message "`Terminated`" shows up and the command aborts.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run an entire Gnome Shell desktop over ssh, so it is normal that you do not manage to. Do not continue to try. It won't work and there is no point in doing that.